# Is there any way to modify the value of a `private static final` field in Java from outside the class?

Tags: java, monkeypatching

I know this is normally rather stupid, but don't shoot me before reading the question. I promise I have a good reason for needing to do this :)

It's possible to modify regular private fields in java using reflection, however Java throws a security exception when trying to do the same for `final` fields.

I'd assume this is strictly enforced, but figured I'd ask anyway just in case someone had figured out a hack to do this.

Let's just say I have an external library with a class "`SomeClass`"

```
public class SomeClass 
{
  private static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass()

  public static SomeClass getInstance(){ 
      return INSTANCE; 
  }

  public Object doSomething(){
    // Do some stuff here 
  }
}
```

I essentially want to Monkey-Patch SomeClass so that I can execute my own version of `doSomething()`. Since there isn't (to my knowledge) any way to really do that in java, my only solution here is to alter the value of `INSTANCE` so it returns my version of the class with the modified method.

Essentially I just want to wrap the call with a security check and then call the original method.

The external library always uses `getInstance()` to get an instance of this class (i.e. it's a singleton).

EDIT: Just to clarify, `getInstance()` is called by the external library, not my code, so just subclassing won't solve the issue.

If I can't do that the only other solution I can think of is to copy-paste entire class and modify the method. This isn't ideal as I'll have to keep my fork up to date with changes to the library. If someone has something a little more maintainable I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Too bad there aren't any extension methods in Java

Comment: I took the liberty to add "static" to getInstance(), as that's probably how it looks like.

Comment: I believe this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/how-to-reinitialize-static-finals-while-unit-testing

Comment: fix your code:
  private static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible. I've used this to monkeypatch naughty threadlocals that were preventing class unloading in webapps. You just need to use reflection to remove the `final` modifier, then you can modify the field.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
private void killThreadLocal(String klazzName, String fieldName) {
    Field field = Class.forName(klazzName).getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);  
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    int modifiers = modifiersField.getInt(field);
    modifiers &= ~Modifier.FINAL;
    modifiersField.setInt(field, modifiers);
    field.set(null, null);
}
```

There is some caching as well around `Field#set`, so if some code has run before it might not necessarily work....

Comment: Maybe if you ran this thread early in the application it would solve the caching issue?

Comment: caching issue is not really an issue. i think it will only happen if another method has attempted to set the field using reflection.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for (Wish I could upvote you more, this is nice and obscure).

Comment: I get java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers in  Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");

Answer (score 5):

Any AOP framework would fit your needs

It would allow you to define a runtime override for the getInstance method allowing you to return whatever class suits your need.

Jmockit uses the ASM framework internally to do the same thing.

Comment: Good answer. The key is not to modify the field, but to intercept the call to retrieve it.

Comment: So this would esssentially be using the same bytecode rewriting trick that JMockit does?

Comment: I am not exactly an expert but there are at least two ways to do it. One using java 1.5 instrumentation API the other using ASM and direct bytecode manipulation

Answer (score 1):

If you really must (though for our problem I'd suggest you use the solution of CaptainAwesomePants) you could have a look at [JMockIt](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/). Although this is intented to be used in unit tests if allows you to redefine arbitrary methods. This is done by modifying the bytecode at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change it with JNI... not sure if that is an option for you.

EDIT: it is possible, but not a good idea.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/pitfalls.html

> 10.9 Violating Access Control Rules
>
> The JNI does not enforce class, field,
>   and method access control restrictions
>   that can be expressed at the Java
>   programming language level through the
>   use of modifiers such as private and
>   final. It is possible to write native
>   code to access or modify fields of an
>   object even though doing so at the
>   Java programming language level would
>   lead to an IllegalAccessException.
>   JNI's permissiveness was a conscious
>   design decision, given that native
>   code can access and modify any memory
>   location in the heap anyway.
>
> Native code that bypasses
>   source-language-level access checks
>   may have undesirable effects on
>   program execution. For example, an
>   inconsistency may be created if a
>   native method modifies a final field
>   after a just-in-time (JIT) compiler
>   has inlined accesses to the field.
>   Similarly, native methods should not
>   modify immutable objects such as
>   fields in instances of
>   java.lang.String or java.lang.Integer.
>   Doing so may lead to breakage of
>   invariants in the Java platform
>   implementation.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought JNI was only used to call external (i.e. C) libraries.

Comment: @JamesDavies: JNI code can also reach back into the JVM and access Java objects and classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. Note: It is not at all thread safe and this doesn't work for constant primitives known at compile time (as they are inlined by the compiler)

```
Field field = SomeClass.class.getDeclareField("INSTANCE");
field.setAccessible(true); // what security. ;)
field.set(null, newValue);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Security Manager doesn't like this- even with setAccessible(true) it doesn't like modifying final values.

Comment: You could try setting System.setSecurityManager(null) and see if you can disable it temporarily. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I will preface this answer by acknowledging that this is not actually an answer to your stated question about modifying a private static final field.  However, in the specific example code mentioned above, I can in fact make it so that you can override doSomething().  What you can do is to take advantage of the fact that getInstance() is a public method and subclass:

```
public class MySomeClass extends SomeClass
{
   private static final INSTANCE = new MySomeClass();

   public SomeClass getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
   }

   public Object doSomething() {
      //Override behavior here!
   }
}
```

Now just invoke MySomeClass.getInstance() instead of SomeClass.getInstance() and you're good to go.  Of course, this only works if you're the one invoking getInstance() and not some other part of the unmodifiable stuff you're working with.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case, getInstance is invoked entirely by the internal code of the library.

Answer (score 0):

with [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) is very simple:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass();

    public static SomeClass getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Object doSomething() {
        return "done!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass someClass = mock(SomeClass.getInstance().getClass());
        when(someClass.doSomething()).thenReturn("something changed!");
        System.out.println(someClass.doSomething());
    }
}
```

this code prints "something changed!"; you can easily replace your singleton instances. My 0.02$ cents.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no external hack available (at least I am not aware of) I would have hacked the class itself. Change the code by adding the security check you want. As such its an external library, you won't be taking the updates regularly, also not many update happens anyway. Whenever that happens I can happily re-do it as it is not a big task anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Here, your problem is good-old Dependency Injection (aka Inversion of Control). Your goal should be to inject your implementation of `SomeClass` instead of monkeypatching it. And yes, this approach requires some changes to your existing design but for the right reasons (name your favorite design principle here) - especially the same object should not be responsible for both creating and using other objects.

I assume the way you're using `SomeClass` looks somewhat like this:

```
public class OtherClass {
  public void doEverything() {
    SomeClass sc = SomeClass.geInstance();
    Object o = sc.doSomething();

    // some more stuff here...
  }
}
```

Instead, what you should do is first create your class that implements the same interface or extends `SomeClass` and then pass that instance to `doEverything()` so your class becomes agnostic to implementation of `SomeClass`. In this case the code that calls `doEverything` is responsible for passing in the correct implementation - whether be the actual `SomeClass` or your monkeypatched `MySomeClass`.

```
public class MySomeClass() extends SomeClass {
  public Object doSomething() {
    // your monkeypatched implementation goes here
  }
}

public class OtherClass {
  public void doEveryting(SomeClass sc) {
    Object o = sc.doSomething();

    // some more stuff here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in the question this won't work because I'm not calling SomeClass directly. I want to change the instance of SomeClass used by an external library- I never call it directly from my code.